# Maya LT extrude tool won't work properly, is it buggy?

Tags: maya, bug

First several hours with Maya LT and already stuck and frustrated. Trying to extrude faces (let's say future legs) but the position of faces from which I am extruding won't stay on its place, it changes and the extrusion happens from a new place, even from there I try to adjust this position, but the edge loop around the selected faces won't move, I try to delete that edge loop, it won't delete it, (tried 'delete', 'ctrl + Delete', delete Edges/Vertex menu option, deleting by vertices, there are no doubles it just removes the selection when I press delete) I managed only when I deleted the faces around that edge loop, which is quite annoying. Maybe someone had a similar issue and knows the solution or I am doing something wrong here? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Could you post an image of the problem with the extrusion so I can better see what the problem is, then I could possibly help?